# Clustering package for meteor framework

Tags: node.js, meteor, machine-learning

Any leads for how to use clustering technique in a meteor project. While googling could find these links: https://github.com/harthur/clusterfck and https://github.com/harthur/brain. Earlier for classification, I am using natural node package and it is working fine.

The steps that I followed for natural node were:
1) mrt install npm
2) In packages.json, made an entry "natural:0.1.27"
3) Used Meteor.require()

But what steps should be used for this clustering package. Also, I have to use clustering (k-means) within classification means first need to apply classification and inside each category of classification, clustering has to be used. Any pointer please how using to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why you would do machine learning in Meteor, which is a framework for building web apps in Javascript. Javascript support for ML stuff is terrible; if you needed to interface the two; you should probably use some other language that reads/writes to the Meteor Mongo database. I do a lot of both Meteor programming and machine learning and I think this is a silly question.

Comment: Okay, I am new in this and first time using this, so which lib you can suggest for doing this and how to integrate this library with meteor application.

Comment: I am implementing machine learning in meteor app in order to make this an intelligent app (requirement of app). Can you please explain whether this implementation of natural (wrapper for meteorite) is not so computationally efficient?. If not, what other lib can you suggest for doing classification and clustering and integrating the two of these things

Comment: I used the clusterfck library that you already found. The kmeans.js and distance.js files are very small, so I merged them into one file in my Meteor client directory. (You need to convert the code in distance.js into an object where each function is a property of the object.) Then make an array of points [[13,7], [54,81], ...]. Call the kmeans function with your points array and the number of clusters you want. @AndrewMao there are a number of valid use cases for realtime, interactive clustering where Meteor is an ideal platform. Not all ML must happen in batch on a server.